# Is it okay to take painkillers on daily basis?

Tags: injury-prevention, back

I am cricketer and whenever i come back home after playing cricket it hurts a lot in my lower back and legs. And every day i take painkillers to reduce my pain. Is it okay to take painkillers on daily basis? I always take painkiller after coming back from my game.

Comment: @Alec please stop closing these questions their very helpful rn I'm taking tylenol on like a  daily basis to deal with back pain and would like to know about the potential dangers
Also what about ibuprofen, naproxen, etc are they safe?